# Creating a custom Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have started learning C++ recently and am currently trying to make my own double linked list. I don't know how it is supposed to be done. Am I suppose to use the already existing list class to store my data and keys or create my own node and linked list class. Or should I just use linked lists that C uses?

Comment: Do you want to implement your own linked list or do you just want to use a linked list?

Comment: Linked lists in C and C++ are essentially the same (at least as far as previous and next pointers). If you use the STL list class, your code is working with objects that do not include previous or next pointers, as the list class will copy data to/from objects into internal nodes that include previous and next pointers.

Comment: If you are creating a custom one it's really purely up to your preference if you want to build upon existing solutions or if you want to implement it completely from scratch.

Comment: C in itself does not have a linked list; you need to do it yourself.

Comment: [Where possible use `std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). If you have to make your own Linked List, two bits of advice: 1. draw out each operation step by step to help visualize what's going on 2. stand on (but properly attribute) the shoulders of giants. Wikipedia often contains good pseudocode. Off topic: While implementing your linked list, pay attention to the effect cache has on performance. Very educational.

Comment: *I have started learning C++ recently and am currently trying to make my own double linked list* -- I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but I have yet to see a beginner in C++ write a **correct** linked list implementation in C++ without *tons* of help from experienced programmers.  In the attempts I've seen, the linked list classes written by beginners are easily broken by trivial means.  Therefore I suggest you use `std::list` and get on with your project, and not get bogged down trying to write your own linked list.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the internet of linked list implementations using C++.  The explanation and usage of a linked list is too large for the StackOverflow format, especially for an answer to one post.

Answer (score 0):

The node structure and the container structure is different.

Single linked list:

```
struct node{
    node* next;
    int data; // Not necessarily an int, but whatever the node will contain.
};

struct container{
    node* head;
};
```

Double linked list:

```
struct node{
    node* next;
    node* prev;  // Unlike the single linked list, a double linked list's node contains a pointer to the previous element as well.
};

struct container{
   node* head;
   node* tail;
};
```

Keep in mind that when you're performing any operation (i.e. push, pop, pull, etc.) you will have to take both of these pointers into consideration.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the double linked list have a tail pointer but the single doesn't?  The point of having a tail pointer is usually to make insertions at the end of the list more efficient. The single list would benefit a lot from a tail pointer.